# Tomcat Web App Not Prompting for Basic Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, servlets

**UPDATE**: I rebooted my computer and now everything works as expected. I do not know what that could possibly have changed that would fix it though, so my question is still open.

I'm following instructions on [This page](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html?page=1) to integrate basic auth into a Java web app running on Tomcat.
I have the following in my web.xml and tomcat-users.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetFile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>[mypackage].GetFile</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Files</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>[mypackage].Files</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetFile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GetFile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Files</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Files</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>MyConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>GetFile</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/GetFile</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>contractor</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd">
    
    <role rolename="contractor"/>
    <user username="contractor" password="******" roles="contractor"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

When I apply this constraint to my web app and browse to http://localhost:8080/MyApp/GetFile, I land on Tomcat's 403 - Forbidden page with the message:

Type: Status Report

"Message: Access to the requested resource has been denied

Description: The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it."

Expected behavior is to receive the browser's basic authentication prompt pop-up asking for credentials. I tried on Chrome, IE, and FireFox, but none display the prompt first. Using NetBeans IDE to deploy the app to local Tomcat.

I have tried restarting Tomcat, restarting NetBeans, clearing cache, browsing to URL in Incognito Mode, and adding credentials in the url, e.g.: http://contractor:******@locahost:8080/etc.

Is there something missing in my xml files to get the auth prompt, or is there another issue?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the "prompt" is a browser feature. The browser you are using may not support asking a user for credentials.

If you want to be assured you get a prompt, the best way is actually to use FORM authentication and create a custom HTML form.

## EDIT

Examine what is being sent back to the browser. If there isn't a `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` header, the browser won't know what to do. I have a feeling this is because you are missing the Realm element in your login config:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>MySecurityRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Comment: I did try multiple browsers to be sure, all with the same results -- but once I rebooted my computer and tried again, all browsers are behaving as desired now. To my knowledge this is a pretty standard feature on any web browser I've ever used.